# Making bread using potassium bicarbonate

Tags: substitutions, bread, leavening

I am thinking about making bread using potassium bicarbonate instead of yeast.

Can I use potassium bicarbonate as a substitute for yeast? Would I just use a regular yeast bread recipe?

Or can I use it in place of regular baking powder? Are there any adjustments necessary?

For example, I would like to use [Hain Featherweight Baking Powder, Sodium Free](https://healthyheartmarket.com/products/baking-powder-featherweight-sodium-free-8-oz).

This is a type of sodium-free baking powder which contains potassium instead. It seems appropriate for people who are on low-sodium diets and want to supplement their potassium intake.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that you can't use it as a direct substitute for sodium-based baking powder?  There are plenty of soda-bread recipes out there.

Comment: Recipe requests are off-topic here because they aren't a good format for this site: StackExchange websites work best with questions that have one answer rather than lots of equally-valid responses. However, a question about whether potassium bicarbonate can be used as a direct substitute in recipes calling for sodium bicarbonate would be on-topic.

Comment: I'm holding off on a VTC as this is a new user with an interesting underlying question - but as it stands it's not answerable within our standards, so this is meant as a delay to allow editing

Comment: Chris, welcome! If you take the [tour] and browse through the [help], especially [ask], you will see that recipe requests are not a good fit for the site. However, there’s a very interesting question hidden in the use of the non-regular baking powder, so I took the liberty to make a drastic edit instead of just closing it. As a hint, start with these questions to get you started in the right direction for switching from yeast to baking powder: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/89004/28879, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/102767/28879, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/103652/28879.

Comment: @bob1 for substitutions, listing the health reasons for attempting to substitute X are fine, even recommended - see the tag description.

Comment: @bob1 "how can I use Y instead of X, because I can't eat X?" is absolutely fine, and I didn't ask for that to be removed. The off-topic bit  is the recipe request